# SMB connection to MS-DOS server from Windows 10 1809+ fails

Tags: windows, server-message-block, ms-dos

We need to interface with a legacy system that run MS DOS 6.22, with a TCP/IP stack and wg1049.exe to create a SMB server (more or less as described on [this site](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Sharing_files_with_DOS)).

Enabling SMB1.0 on our Windows system we could connect to this server swimmingly, but this stopped working with (I think) feature update 1809.

When comparing wireshark logs, I can see that after protocol negotiation (the server selects `PC NETWORK PROGRAM 1.0` from the list) Windows just stops responding, instead of initiating a Tree Connect Request. SMB1.0 is still enabled.

What can I do to re-establish contact to the legacy hardware from a current Windows?

Note: We know that all this is quite horrible, but we need to support this for for some time longer. All systems are airgapped from the evil outside world.

Comment: Can you afford a "proxy" server in the middle, with lower version of Windows, or even Linux with Samba software? It could mount a DOS server, and then re-export the mounted directory via modern protocol to your Windows 10.

Comment: Nice Idea! This whole system is integrated in some legacy hardware, so an actual additional server does not work, but maybe a virtual one...